# Navigation back bar text

Tags: ios

I have implemented a `navigationController` from ViewController1 to ViewController2. I am getting the tittle of the ViewController1 in **Back BarButton** of the `NavigationBar` at ViewController2.

When i change the tittle of the **Back BarButton** in the ViewController2 the Tittle in the ViewController1 Changes.?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"";
```

How Can i do that without Changing the Tittle of the ViewController1

Comment: add a button in UIBARBUTTON ITEM for leftNavigationBarItem

Answer (score 0):

You should create your custom UIBarButtonItem.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:YOUR_SELECTOR] autorelease];
```

Comment: @Cyph3r update your question with what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

In ViewController1

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       self.navigationItem.title = @"someTitle1";
}
```

and in ViewController2

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];
       self.navigationItem.title = @"someTitle2";
       self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
       initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BACK_BUTTON_IMG.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
       target:self action:@selector(YOUR_SELECTOR_METHOD)];
    }
```